# Google map api and background-attachment: fixed issue in webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've got problem with connecting Google Map api v3.

I have 3 elements with `background-attachment:fixed` property.
If map is connected background of these elements not updating on scroll, only if some of css property will be changed with js or devtool.

There no parent elements with `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

Web site is based on customized themeforest template Urip!!

[Screenshot link](https://leto2g.storage.yandex.net/rdisk/10f2ad69c6a2ed10111de6dd3432325b9be6a2712c096a691c3ab77a1a3bc0ef/inf/TIFBfRkIltj2FBXXMBAzM8jtQkqkPYBtUMa1CoGF60JMjn70WOCO6RMXpJ79g7r_gPhS2EEguz_DYaVabvo7ZA==?uid=0&filename=2015-06-27-15-24-14-Urip-Landing-Page-Template---Hero-Form-Layout---Google-Chrome.png&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&tknv=v2&rtoken=2d40c6642a4bf1addd9b0f9d1ad653d7&force_default=no)

UPD: Map parent container has propery `position: fixed`. Map has property `transform: translateZ(0px);`.
I found that if these properties are turned off, background works fine.
But if map appears in the window, bug comes back.
So the problem is in appearing background fixed element and map in the window at the same time.

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to set every div ( except divs with `transform: matrix( ... )` )

```
transform: none !important;
```

Code result:

```
#map, #map > *, 
#map > .gm-style > div:not(:first-child), 
#map > .gm-style > div:not(:first-child) div, 
#map > .gm-style > div:first-child > div:nth-child(2), 
#map > .gm-style > div > div div{
  transform: none !important;
}
```

Hope it will help somebody